# Jmeter - How Can I Replace a string and resend it?

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to create a script that will take a URL out of a response and send it out again.
Using the regular expression extractor I've succeeded  in taking the wanted URL, but it holds "&" so naturally when sending it out the request fails.
Example:
GET http://[ia-test01.inner-active.mobi:8080/simpleM2M/ClientUpdateStatus?cn=WS2006&v=2_1_0-iOS-2_0_3_7&ci=99999&s=3852719769860497476&cip=113-170-93-111&po=642&re=1&lt=0&cc=VN&acp=&pcp=]/

I'm trying to replace the "&" with a "&".
I've tried: ${__javaScript(${url}.replace("&","&"))}
But it did not work. I've tried the regex function as well- the same.
I'm not sure the IP field in the request supports the us e of functions.

I'm currently trying to use the beanshell post-processor. But I'm pretty sure there is a simpler solution I'm missing.

Comment: Can you say what you do exactly? Are you trying to use a variable in an HTTP request and replacing it with a value? If so, where do you use the variable? As server name? Or as Path? Or other?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what you're trying to get by replacing `&` with `&` however will try to respond.

1. First of all: given multiple `&` instances you need to use `replaceall` function, not replace
2. Second: replace / replaceall functions take a **RegEx** as parameter, so you'll need to escape your `&`
3. If you're trying to substitute URL Path in realtime, you'll need [Beanshell Pre Processor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell), not the Post Processor

Sample Beanshell Pre-Processor code

```
import java.net.URL;

URL myURL = sampler.getUrl();
String path = myURL.getPath();
String path_replaced = path.replaceAll("\\&", "&");
vars.put("NEW_PATH", path_replaced);
```

After that put `${NEW_PATH}` to "Path:" section of your HTTP Request.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Solution with less code:

- Install the [Custom JMeter Functions plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/)
- Use the following syntax

  ```
   ${__strReplace(ImAGoodBoy,Good,Bad,replaceVar)}
  ```
- ‘ImAGoodBoy’ is a string in which replacement will take place
- ‘Good’ is a substring to be replaced
- ‘Bad’ is the replacement string
- ‘replaceVar’ is a variable to save result string

[Refer this URL for more info!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-custom-jmeter-functions-plugin-part2)

Answer (score 1):

Thank a lot. However, i see from a recent experience that to replace a character that is actually a RegExp special character, like \ " ( ) etc, you need to put 3 backslashes and not 1, not 2. This is weird.

so you write

```
var res = str.replaceAll("\\\\u003c", "<");
```

to replace `\u003c with <`

Comment: So, there are 4 backslashes: "\\\\". It happens for double-quotes too, sometimes: """". So usual: This is Java, dudes! ;) It works this way for 20 years already, use to it.