# Format the stirng value

Tags: string, jmeter

I have the following value in a variable.

```
9.2.345.113619.2-218.98721247546.30582.1191562771895.2
```

I want to change the format of this value to `9-2-345-113619-2-218-98721247546-30582-1191562771895-2` and store it in another variable. Is there any function in JMeter that can do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jmeter - How Can I Replace a string and resend it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137089/jmeter-how-can-i-replace-a-string-and-resend-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your value is stored in Jmeter_variable

Then place one bean-shell sampler and write below mentioned code

```
value=vars.get("Jmeter_variable").replaceAll("\\.","-");
vars.put("Updated_variable",value);
```

Now use `${updated_variable}`, where you want to use

Comment: Getting the error
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2016-03-28 11:07:52 IST
Load time: 2
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 500
Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``value=vars.get(9.2.345.113619.2-218.98721247546.30582.1191562771895.2).replaceAl . . . '' Encountered "( 9.2 .345" at line 1, column 15.


Response headers:

SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null

Comment: are you directly placing your value into vars.get method (as shown in your comment)? Is it a Jmeter variable or not ?

Comment: if this is not a Jmeter variable and you are defining by your self in beanshell smapler than use this code ---  String value="9.2.345.113619.2-218.98721247546.30582.1191562771895.2";
value=value.replaceAll("\\.","-");
vars.put("Updated_variable",value);

Comment: This is my code
   
value=vars.get(${studyid}).replaceAll("\\.","-");
vars.put("newStudyID",value);

JMeter variable ${studyid} holds the value 9.2.345.113619.2.218.98721247546.30582.1191562771895.2

Answer (score 0):

1. Inline, using [__javaScript()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) function

   ```
   ${__javaScript("9.2.345.113619.2-218.98721247546.30582.1191562771895.2".split(".").join("-");,)}
   ```
2. Against variable using [__Beanshell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) function

   ```
   ${__BeanShell(vars.put("newStudyID"\, vars.get("").replaceAll("\\\\."\,"-")),)}
   ```
3. In any Beanshell Test Element:

   ```
   vars.put("newStudyID", vars.get("").replaceAll("\\\\.","-"));
   ```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on using scripting in your JMeter test.